# How to run /deploy a React+redux app which is created by using create-react-app (as per document ) in Apache Tomcat

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have created react application using react+redux which has some API call  its running fine with npm start on localhost:3000 . but i wanna to deploy onto Apache tomcat or any other server. is it possible .? if yes then tell how to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just run `npm run build` to make production build, then copy build folder and drop in public folder of your web server it will work.

Checkout official docs of [Create react app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#deployment) on deployment for more details.

Comment: yup i  tried this one . my project has many  components folder and images but when used npm run build i got build folder with only one index . i didnt get my components folders

Comment: Thats fine. your all components are bundled in one Js file inside `build/static/js` folder.

Comment: i see so now  if i copy , paste inside the Apache webapp then if i run build folder it is it will work or still should i do some other  configurations

Comment: great Abhishek i will try and let u know

Comment: am getting blank page

Comment: Deployment has nothing to with react. You have to follow same steps you perform while deploying any HTML, CSS, JS project. Make sure your are doing it correctly and it will work.

Comment: hi Abhishek i found the issue and fixed ., the  issue  was just with Router path . now its working fine . great Abhishek  thanks

Comment: @Ramusesan I have the same issue "blank page" how did u fix the Router path?

Answer (score 1):

**This will work on Tomcat 9.x:**

As mentioned before, use **npm run build** 
to create the build artifacts (inside your app's 'build' folder).

Use hot deploy on tomcat: just copy the build folder to **TOMCAT_HOME/webapps** folder, and change the name to your app's name, e.g. '**your-app-here**':

[image: this is how your tomcat webapps folder should look like:]

Browse to http://localhost:8080/your-app-here/

Note that the page might fail to load with error 404, due to missing static files (css, js etc.); in that case you will need to move the static folder from your-app to **TOMCAT_HOME/webapps** folder.

Reload the page or restart tomcat.

Goodluck!